# react-highlightjs not highlighting syntax code as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, syntax-highlighting

I am using `react-highlight` to highlight code in my next.js app, but I am getting the following code highlight while using the `a11y-dark` theme

[image: getting]

But on official website of [highlightjs.org](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/). They have given following highlight using the same theme(`a11y-dark`)

[image: expected]

There is a huge difference between both. I am not able to get where this difference is coming from.

I also imported stylesheets correctly. My next.js code is as follows. Can anyone tell how to fix this. Thanks!

```
'use client'
import styles from './Code.module.css'
import Highlight from 'react-highlight' 
import '../../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css'

export const Code = (props)=>{


    return<>
    <section className={styles.code}>
        <div className={styles.type}>
            Type:
            <select name="type" className={styles.type_select}>
                <option value="vjs">Vanilla Javascript</option>
                <option value="rjs">ReactJS / NextJS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.main_code}>
            <Highlight language="javascript">{props.code}</Highlight>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue with react-highlight is but there's a separate package that will give you what you want: [react-syntax-highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter)

Full code here:

```
import React from 'react';
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { a11yDark } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

const CodeBlock: React.FC<{ codestring: string }> = ({ codestring }) => {
  return (
    <SyntaxHighlighter
      language="javascript"
      style={a11yDark}
      showLineNumbers>
      {codestring}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>
  );
};

function App() {

  var code = `function $initHighlight(block, cls) {
    try {
      if (cls.search(/\bno\-highlight\b/) != -1)
        return process(block, true, 0x0F) +
               \` class="\${cls}"\`;  
    } catch (e) {
      /* handle exception */
    }
    for (var i = 0 / 2; i < classes.length; i++) {
      if (checkCondition(classes[i]) === undefined)
          return /\d+[\s/]/g;
      }
       return 0xA;
    }
    
    export  $initHighlight;`;

  return (
    <div className="w-1/2 bg-blue-700">
      <CodeBlock codestring={code} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tested the a11yDark style and it matches your second screenshot:
[image]